# C# WCF pass data from Task running on Server to Client

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am new in WCF area. I want to make screenshot on server and send them to client with WCF nettcpbinding. On Client I want to update UI with those data. But I do not know what i need and how to do this. I read about full duplex contract with callback but i dont know is it really needed.

**WPFClient.cs**

```
namespace WPFClient
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        byte[] GetData();
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string bytesSum;

        public string BytesSum
        {
            get { return bytesSum; }
            set { bytesSum = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("BytesSum"); }
        }


        public ViewModel()
        {
            ChannelFactory<IService> channel = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(@"net.tcp://localhost:8554/"));
            IService s = channel.CreateChannel();
            //How to get data from server and update UI?
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
namespace Server
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        byte[] GetData();
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public byte[] GetData()
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[5000];
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class ScreenLogger
    {
        public byte[] GenerateImage()
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[5000];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = (byte)rnd.Next();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            var imageTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                byte[] GeneratedBytes = GenerateImage();
                //How to send GeneratedBytes to client?
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScreenLogger screenLogger = new ScreenLogger();
            screenLogger.Start();

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetTcpBinding(), new Uri(@"net.tcp://localhost:8554/"));
            Console.WriteLine("Server start");
            host.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `IService` interface is not a duplex contract. It should specify a callback contract that the client, i.e. your view model in the client application, implements. The service implementation on the server side will then invoke operations on the callback.

You can get a reference to the callback using the `OperationContext` class in your service implemenation like this:

```
var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IYourDuplexCallback>();
```

You then call a method of the callback to pass data from the server to the client. There is an example of how to create and setup a duplex WCF service available on MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services).

**How to: Create a Duplex Contract:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract

Comment: @A191919: Did you take a look at the example or what happened?

Answer (score 0):

To my eyes, and according to what your example is doing, it looks like you just need to get the results of the `Task` in a space that is available to your service instance.

My simplistic version has a property on the service contract and implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    // not exposed 
    byte[] TaskResults { get; set; }

    [OperationContract]
    byte[] GetData();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public byte[] TaskResults { get; set; }
    public byte[] GetData()
    {
        //byte[] result = new byte[5000];
        //return result;
        return TaskResults;
    }
}
```

And then change the `ScreenLogger.Start()` signature to be `ScreenLogger.Start(Action<byte[]> bytesAction)` invoking that action with the results of the task work.

```
public void Start(Action<byte[]> bytesAction)
    {
        var imageTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                  {
                                                      //var GeneratedBytes = GenerateImage();

                                                      //How to send GeneratedBytes to client?
                                                      bytesAction(GenerateImage());
                                                  });
    }
```

And finally passing an action that assigns the results of the task to the service property.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ScreenLogger screenLogger = new ScreenLogger();
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));

        screenLogger.Start(ba => ((Service)host.SingletonInstance).TaskResults = ba);

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetTcpBinding(), new Uri(@"net.tcp://localhost:8554/"));
        Console.WriteLine("Server start");
        host.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
```

With the client code (simplified) looking like this.

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    private string bytesSum;

    public string BytesSum
    {
        get { return bytesSum; }
        set { bytesSum = value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged("BytesSum"); }
    }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        ChannelFactory<IService> channel = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new NetTcpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(@"net.tcp://localhost:8554/"));
        IService s = channel.CreateChannel();

        //How to get data from server and update UI?
        s.GetData().ToList().ForEach(b => Console.Write(b));
    }


    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {

    }
}
```